# Fast Methods for analyzing large scale Walker constellations

Tags: low-earth-orbit, analysis

I have been doing some research and with the growing scale of large number of small sats and I am trying to see if there has been work done to study the coverage capability for these constellations.

Right now the only way I can think is to propagate every satellite over a given period of time (30 -60 days), and compute its access to all the desired points, and then move forward to the next satellite.

Any thoughts would be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look at the 'technical comparison of three low earth orbit satellite constellation systems to provide global broadband' (*del Portillo et al.*). Available [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0094576518320368).

In this work authors focus on the mega-constellation throughput estimation and some analysis in terms of ground infrastructure is also present. I assume you might use some of their assumptions.

I would also like to recommend you the SaVi software. Their web-site[2](https://savi.sourceforge.io/) include numerous examples of academic works, some of which might be also useful for your goal.

Hope it helps.

Cheers